# Meteor : passing router parameter to get Collection data without results

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router, mongo-collection

I'm fairly new to meteor and have encountered a problem while trying to use Iron Router to pass a url parameter to a Collection and retrieve some data for display.

Specifically, I have a Collection with events and I'd like to have a page that display a single one in more detail.

**PS:** I've used Iron Router and Meteor's publish/subscribe logic succesfully for other tasks, such as displaying all events, creating them and saving them to a personal list.

---

*event.html*

```html
<template name="event">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>{{content}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

*router.js*

```js
this.route('event',{
    path: '/event/:_id',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('Events');
    },
    data: function () {
        return Events.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

---

Publishing happens on the server in publish.js and subscribing in the router
*publish.js*

```js
Meteor.publish('Events', function () {
    return Events.find();
});
```

*router.js*

```js
Router.configure({

    (..)

    waitOn: function() {
        return [
          Meteor.subscribe('Events'),
          Meteor.subscribe('myEvents')
        ];
    }
});
```

---

I've been looking at this tutorial by Manuel Schoebel [link](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial)

All is fine up until the point where the Collection lookup is happening. When I log the result data from the Collection, it's `undefined`

```js
data: function () {
    var event = Events.findOne(this.params._id);
    console.log(event);
    return event;
}
```

Comment: try changing this ```var event = Events.findOne(this.params._id);``` to ```var event = Events.findOne({_id: eventId}); //where var eventId = this.params._id``` and return ```{event: event}```

Comment: What does `console.log(this.params._id)` give you?

Comment: How about Events.findOne({_id: ObjectId(this.params._id)});

Comment: Silly enough, I placed a `:` some place it should not have been.
Code is fully functional now :)

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakenly, I placed a `:` where it should not have been.
Closing question.